# Set Ember application width to 100%

Tags: css, ember.js

I need to set the width of my Ember app to 100%. As is, it seems to be stuck at 1450px wide.

The application level element has two classes, an "emberID" and "ember-view", but of course I can't set CSS by these - the ID changes and everything ember does is set in an ember view. Can I perhaps add a class to this top level ember element?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do in order to avoid using the deprecated `Ember.View` is wrap the `{{outlet}}` in your `application.hbs` template with a div:

```
<div class="application">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

And then give that div the following css:

```
.application {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help I'm afraid. Ember still creates a div a level above this.